# VBA - merging sorted and deduplicated liste items

Tags: vba, sorting, arraylist, merge, duplicates

This is for VBA.

I have a need to merge various array lists with string contents into one, sorted, deduped array list.

I am scraping this information and creating array lists as I go through various links.

What is the best way to then merge the array lists, where the output is an array list of strings where they are deduped and sorted.

E.g

input:

array list 1:   text 1 text ,  text 2 text,  text 3 text

array list 2:   text 7 text,  text 9 text, text 11 text

array list 3:   text 1 text,  text 2 text,  text 10 text

output:

text 1 text, text 2 text, text 3 text, text 7 text, text 9 text, text 10 text, text 11 text

Comment: The best way is always to find one point to start from and then put one foot in front of the other. Show us the first step you have taken.

Comment: @variatus https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60662952/creating-2d-array-lists-in-vba  please answer this one, it has code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize a 'combined' array list, as you parse through each website, store the contents in a temporary array 'temp'.

```
For int i = 0 to temp.count

if combined.containss ( temp(i)) Then

'do nothing

Else

combined.add (temp(i))

End If

next i
```